# how to get variables declared with var statement in function block?

Tags: javascript, scope, var

example:

```
var obj = {
  count: 12,
  bbb: function() {
    var count = 6;
    console.log(this.count,globalThis.count,count)
  }
}
```

I know that `this` is a reference of `obj`, ant `globalThis` for `window`, but how can I get `count` which the value of is 6? Won't it be added to the global object and can be obtained by `this`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 0):

`

```
var obj = {
  count: 12,
  bbb: function() {
    count = 6;
    console.log(this.count,globalThis.count,count)
  }
}
obj.bbb()
```

`

you can remove the var from the count inside the function then it will be considered as global this.